# Preferred way to make JPA / Hibernate Entities Immutable / Thread-safe

Tags: hibernate, jpa, thread-safety, entity, immutability

I have a somewhat normalized database with entitity objects comprised of other entities, and I will be publishing the root entity on it's own and in collections in a java web application in both the session and application scope.  I am wonder what the best way is to convert the root Entity object into an immutable object that is thread-safe and able to be published in a web app environment.  The ways I have found are:

1) Convert the entity to an immutable object in the DAO using a builder.  This seems like the most programming, i.e. having to iterate over the entire entity to set the immutable object, but it also seems like the safest for a multi-threaded environment.

2) Use a factory/builder that casts the Entity into a read-only interface composed of get methods, described on this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560167/possible-to-have-immutable-jpa-entities). This seems cool, but I have never tried it in practice, and it doesn't seem to be completely thread-safe as the fields aren't final and the object is mutable on some level, just not by any app using the read-only version.

3) Use something vendor specific like Hibernate's @Immutable annotation.  This sounds good at first, but after making sure that no collections are returning immutable values, it starts to look like option 1 above, where I am just building an immutable replica of the original entity by iterating over all of it's values and converting them into an immutable version.  Also, I couldn't find any examples of this where an @Immutable entity was used and published in a web application.  Does anyone have any experience with this, is it thread-safe?

Example Entity Relationship (incomplete and non-functional, just to show nested qualities):

```
class A {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private B b;
}

class B {

    @Id
    private long id

    private String something;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable
    private List<C> cs;
}

class C {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String otherName;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Sadly, the `@Immutable` annotation appears to be used (from all the examples and documentation that I've seen) to keep modifications to the entity from being pushed to the backing database. It still seems to require mutable fields and a default constructor. I think #1 really is your only solution if you want both immutability and hibernate.

Answer (score 3):

For my opinion option :

Create private default constructor (default constructor required by hibernate).
Create complete constructor for all fields and define them as private.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I used #1 above for thread-safety in the Java web app environment.